# Difference between Array and List in Vala

Tags: arrays, list, vala

As stated in the title, what is major difference between [GLib.Array](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Array.html) and [GLib.List](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.List.html) in Vala language? They look very similar in the tutorial pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GLib.Array` is an [array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-data-structure/).  `GLib.List` is a ([doubly linked](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/)) list.  Here is an article comparing (singly linked) lists and arrays: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-vs-array/

It's also worth mentioning that with `GLib.List` (and `GLib.SList`), the pointer actually points to the head of the list.  That means that if you're storing a reference to the list in one place and modifying the list somewhere else you'll likely end up with some memory management problems.  Unless you understand what's going on under the hood you're probably much better off using [`Gee.List`](https://valadoc.org/gee-0.8/Gee.List.html) (or one of the other data structures in libgee).

In Vala you'll generally want to use [`GLib.GenericArray`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.GenericArray.html) instead of `GLib.Array`, unless you're interfacing with something which requires a `GLib.Array`.  `GLib.Array` just doesn't work quite as well with how generics work in Vala; `GArray` is actually a bit weird in C as well, and just doesn't translate very well to Vala. `GLib.GenericArray` is an alternate binding for `GLib.PtrArray` (which is a `GPtrArray` at the C level, not a `GArray`).